# Google app engine Image GIF execute_transforms LargeImageError

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I'm resizing various images with GAE Image service like this:

```
from google.appengine.api images
img = images.Image(image_data=get_file_content(image_file_path))
img.resize(width=600)
thumbnail_data = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
```

It works fine but for an animated GIF image, `execute_transforms` raises `LargeImageError`. The image size is 143KB and has a resolution of 607x571px. This happens in GAE but not in my local development server.

In [Images Python API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) says that the image *must be no larger than 32 megabytes*. But this is not the case.

Comment: Try a very small animated GIF (i.e. 5x5 pixels). See if you get the same error.

Comment: TBH I'd be surprised if it seamlessly converted animated gifs...

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I've tried this 40x40 image http://fossies.org/linux/www/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.zip/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/images/animated-overlay.gif and in GAE transforms the image with no error but produces a totally black image, while in local development server produces the correct image. Then I've tried this image http://forums.autodesk.com/autodesk/attachments/autodesk/120/34295/1/animatedLoader.gif and the result is good in both cases.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood the local development server scales GIFs
with no issues. But in any case, if GIF images were incompatible then why is the error LargeImageError raised? Shouldn't the GAE docs say that GIFs are incompatible?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood in the GAE docs says that animated GIFs are compatible https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/#Python_Image_formats

Comment: good to know, tnx. As to the "local" issue, I understand your local version of PIL is used which might well differ from the version that's actually used in production. So perhaps that might explain it.

Comment: I'm using PIL 1.1.7 in both places.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a legitimate bug to me. It is possible that the Image service somehow treats all frames in an animated GIF as a single image, exceeding the size limit.

Note that black image is not a bug. JPEG does not support transparency:

> transparent_substitution_rgb
>
> If transparent pixels are not supported
>   in the destination image format, the default is to substitute black.
>   You can replace this default color with another substitution by
>   specifying it in 32-bit RGB format.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bug, one of the many images service bugs/shortcomings, I suspect a major improvement to the images service should be on it's way, it has been lagging behind the latest resolution improvements / retina screens etc.

Please star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10988) - they fix things when a lot of people star an issue, I've also linked this question over the issue tracker